# How to display error messages inside the modal on click of the td element in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, modal-dialog

For every validations if the isError is true , it should display the error message in the modal.
How to display the error messages in the modal for each validations on click of view errors
[validated column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZUX0.png)
validation and table in jquery, where globalfiledata is the array of values-

```
 function ValidateBulkdata(globalfiledata) {
 var tbody = $('#tblCsvRecords tbody'),
  props = ["ShipmentType", "SCAC", "ShipmentControlNumber", "ProvinceofLoading", "ShipperName", 
     "ConsigneeName"];

     $.each(globalfiledata, function (key, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var isError = false;

        $.each(props, function (key, prop) {
        $('<td>').html(value[prop]).appendTo(tr);
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/;

        if (prop === "ShipmentType" && value.ShipmentType !== ("Regular Bill" || "Section 321")) {
            isError = true;
          //show error message- enter valid shipment type in the modal
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipmentControlNumber) || (value.ShipmentControlNumber.length) > 12) {
            isError = true;
           //show error message- enter valid Shipment Control Number in the modal
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipperName) || (value.ShipperName.length) > 60) {
            isError = true;
            //show error message- enter valid Shipper Name in the modal
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipperAddress) || (value.ShipperAddress.length) > 55) {
            isError = true;
            //show error message- enter valid Shipper Address in the modal

        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipperCity) || (value.ShipperCity.length) > 30) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipperPostal) || (value.ShipperPostal.length) > 15) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ShipperEmail) || (value.ShipperEmail.length) > 50) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ConsigneeName) || (value.ConsigneeName.length) > 60) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ConsigneeAddress) || (value.ConsigneeAddress.length) > 55) {
            isError = true;
        }

        else if (!regex.test(value.ConsigneeCity) || (value.ConsigneeCity.length) > 30) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ConsigneePostal) || (value.ConsigneePostal.length) > 15) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.ConsigneeEmail) || (value.ConsigneeEmail.length) > 50) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.CommoditiesDescription) || (value.CommoditiesDescription.length) > 45) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.MarksNumbers) || (value.MarksNumbers.length) > 30) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.HazardousMaterialCode1) || (value.HazardousMaterialCode1.length) > 10) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.HazardousMaterialCode2) || (value.HazardousMaterialCode2.length) > 10) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.HazardousMaterialCode3) || (value.HazardousMaterialCode3.length) > 10) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.EmergencyContactName1) || (value.EmergencyContactName1.length) > 24) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.EmergencyContactName2) || (value.EmergencyContactName2.length) > 24) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.EmergencyContactName3) || (value.EmergencyContactName3.length) > 24) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.Phone1) || (value.Phone1.length) > 256) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.Phone2) || (value.Phone1.length) > 256) {
            isError = true;
        }
        else if (!regex.test(value.Phone3) || (value.Phone1.length) > 256) {
            isError = true;
        }

       
    });
   var td = $('<td>');
    if (isError) {
        var link = td.append('<a href="#" id="OpenPopup">View Errors</a>');
        $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/error_red.jpg').wrap(link).appendTo(td);
        $("#OpenPopup").on('click', function () {
            $('#divShipmentValidation').modal('show');

        });
    }
    else {
        $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/success_green.png').appendTo(td);
    }
    td.appendTo(tr);
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

}

html table-

```
<div id="tablediv" class="table-responsive">                                           
<table id="tblCsvRecords" class="table table3-1 bg-white no-margin-bottom">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Shipment Type </th>
<th>SCAC </th>
<th>Shipment Control Number </th>
<th>Port of Loading </th>
<th>Shipper Name </th>
<th>Consignee Name </th>
<th>Validated </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

modal html-

```
  <div id="divShipmentValidation" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xLarge">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Shipment Validation Messages</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal1-body">
               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Hi , how does `ValidateBulkdata` function gets called ? Also ,which message should get displayed ?

Comment: This is the csv file upload to html table, so on click of button ,. csv file is read and this function- ValidateBulkdata  is called inside reader.onload . 
For different validations, i have commented the error message that needs to be displayed inside modal  in the code above . values needs to be proper validated and show errors accrdingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could pass Error Message to a Modal by passing error message text to below function

```
    function showErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
      $('#divShipmentValidation').modal('show');
      $('#divShipmentValidation .modal1-body').text(errorMessage);
    };
```

Comment: error message is displaying but its isError is not working as expected, how should i concatenate that, because if isError is true for first then it is coming out of the if else and not validating the other values of elseif.

Comment: that is because how IF Else IF works, if the first condition IF condition is true it won't go down to next one which is the 1st Else If. if you want to display all the errors then you can just go with individual If statements

Comment: var errorMessage = "";
    function checkError() {
        if (1 != 0) {
            errorMessage = "1st error message";
        }

        if (1 != 2) {
            errorMessage += "2nd error message";
        }

        showErrorMessage(errorMessage);
    }